# Getting direct download links from hidden Vimeo-Files

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I have the requirement to download Video-Files from a "pro"-Account on vimeo. These Videos are NOT visible for the public audience.

I have a user-account that allows me to access these videos. When using the API with my account with the "api-playground" I can also access that video with its id.

But while I can display direct download links with that account on the website, the api-call does not provide any Download-Link:

```
GET https://api.vimeo.com/videos/[number]
```

Response:

```
{
    "uri": "/videos/[number]:[somekey]",
    "name": "Pivot Bin",
    "description": null,
    "link": "https://vimeo.com/[number]/[somekey]",
    "duration": 178,
    "width": 1920,
    "language": null,
    "height": 1080,
    [...]
    "privacy": {
        "view": "unlisted",
        "embed": "whitelist",
        "download": false,
        "add": false,
        "comments": "nobody"
    },
    "pictures": {
    [...]
    },
    "tags": [],
    "stats": {


"plays": 118
},
"categories": [],
"metadata": {
 [...]
},
"user": {
  [...]
},

"last_user_action_event_date": "2018-05-16T14:29:13+00:00",
"app": null,
"status": "available",
"resource_key": "xxx",
"upload": {
    "status": "complete",
    "link": null,
    "upload_link": null,
    "complete_uri": null,
    "form": null,
    "approach": null,
    "size": null,
    "redirect_url": null
},
"transcode": {
    "status": "complete"
}
```

}

I am aware that download is disabled for the public audience in privacy - settings, but with the very same user account I can access the direct links to that video on the web.

Is there any way to get these links using the API or do I have to "crawl" the site to get those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the download links to return in the video response, the bearer token must be authenticated as the video owner, and the API app must also be created by the video owner. In other words, every part of the chain must belong to the same user -- you can only ever get download links for videos on your own account.

Also, team members cannot get video file metadata on a parent account. Again, those download links can only be retrieved when authenticated as the video owner.

I hope this information helps!

Comment: So could this be simply just an issue of the "api playground"?

Comment: Yeah, try a REST client like Postman, or command-line curl instead of the API Playground.

Comment: I downvoted, because I received the answer from Vimeo-Support (see other answer) and with that knowledge this answer is a bit misleading.

Comment: @OleAlbers I edited my answer to include a note about team membership. In all likelihood, when you wrote into Vimeo support I was probably the agent who answered your question.

Answer (score 3):

I received an answer from the vimeo - support and wanted to share this with those who might have the same problem:

> Currently, team members and administrators cannot manage or create
>   developer apps for a parent PRO, Premium, or Business account. We have
>   blocked this ability because developer apps can take actions and
>   modify a Vimeo account's settings outside of the team structure.

So sadly this does not work (yet).